# How to get into postgres using your username?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am using a postgresql on Ubuntu. It already has my username `testuser` that I have checked using the following command:

```
\du
```

But whenever I create a database, it says that the owner is `postgres`:

```
create database tempdb;
```

I want the user of `tempdb` to be `tempuser` rather than `postgres`. Could you tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
CREATE DATABASE tempdb OWNER testuser;
```

as per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `psql`? If so, the `--username` flag will allow you to connect as `testuser`.

Comment: I have logged in using the following command: `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: Sounds like you already solved your issue, but `sudo -u postgres psql --username testuser` might also help.